# Add two textviews side by side in a TableLayout dynamically

Tags: java, android, dynamic, rows, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to add rows dynamically in a table. I need to add two TextViews side by side in each row. This has to be done dynamically. I have written the code that creates rows dynamically. I'm unable to add a second TextView on the side.

**activity.xml**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1"
    android:id="@+id/tableView" 
    android:layout_weight="1"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</TableLayout>`
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableView);
    for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {

        TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
        TextView qty = new TextView(this);
        qty.setText("10");
        row.addView(qty);
        ll.addView(row,i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the `LayoutParams`:

```
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableView);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView qty = new TextView(this);
    qty.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    qty.setText("10");
    row.addView(qty);

    ll.addView(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableView);
TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
    TextView qty = new TextView(this);
    qty.setText("10");
    row.addView(qty);
}
ll.addView(row);
```

You were adding two different rows with a single TextView each and not a row with two TextViews.

You need two levels of for.